# C# Convolution filter for any size matrix (1x1, 3x3, 5x5, ...) not fully applied

Tags: c#, image-processing, convolution

I'm making a convolution filter for my project and I managed to make it for any size of matrix but as it gets bigger I noticed that not all bits are changed.
Here are the pictures showing the problem:

First one is the original
[image]
Filter: Blur 9x9

Filter: EdgeDetection 9x9:
[image]

As you can see, there is a little stripe that is never changed and as the matrix gets bigger, the stripe also gets bigger (in 3x3 it wasn't visible)

My convolution matrix class:

```
    public class ConvMatrix
{
    public int Factor = 1;
    public int Height, Width;
    public int Offset = 0;
    public int[,] Arr;

    //later I assign functions to set these variables
    ...
}
```

The filter function:

```
    Bitmap Conv3x3(Bitmap b, ConvMatrix m)
{
    if (0 == m.Factor)
        return b;

    Bitmap bSrc = (Bitmap)b.Clone();
    BitmapData bmData = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height),
                        ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                        PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    BitmapData bmSrc = bSrc.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bSrc.Width, bSrc.Height),
                       ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                       PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    int stride = bmData.Stride;

    System.IntPtr Scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
    System.IntPtr SrcScan0 = bmSrc.Scan0;

        unsafe
        {
            byte* p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;
            byte* pSrc = (byte*)(void*)SrcScan0;
            int nOffset = stride - b.Width * m.Width;
            int nWidth = b.Width - (m.Size-1);
            int nHeight = b.Height - (m.Size-2);

            int nPixel = 0;

            for (int y = 0; y < nHeight; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < nWidth; x++)
                {
                    for (int r = 0; r < m.Height; r++)
                    {
                        nPixel = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < m.Width; i++)
                            for (int j = 0; j < m.Height; j++)
                            {
                                nPixel += (pSrc[(m.Width * (i + 1)) - 1 - r + stride * j] * m.Arr[j, i]);
                            }

                        nPixel /= m.Factor;
                        nPixel += m.Offset;

                        if (nPixel < 0) nPixel = 0;
                        if (nPixel > 255) nPixel = 255;
                        p[(m.Width * (m.Height / 2 + 1)) - 1 - r + stride * (m.Height / 2)] = (byte)nPixel;
                    }
                    p += m.Width;
                    pSrc += m.Width;
                }
                p += nOffset;
                pSrc += nOffset;
            }
        }

    b.UnlockBits(bmData);
    bSrc.UnlockBits(bmSrc);
    return b;
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your code explicitly stops short of the edges. The calculation for the limits for your outer loops (`nWidth` and `nHeight`) shouldn't involve the size of the matrix, they should be equal to the size of your bitmap.

When you do this, if you imagine what happens when you lay the center point of your matrix over each pixel in this case (because you need to read from all sizes of the pixel) the matrix will partially be outside of the image near the edges.

There are a few approaches as to what to do near the edges, but a reasonable one is to clamp the coordinates to the edges. I.e. when you would end up reading a pixel from outside the bitmap, just get the nearest pixel from the edge (size or corner).

I also don't understand why you need five loops - you seem to be looping through the height of the matrix twice. That doesn't look right. All in all the general structure should be something like this:

```
for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++) {
  for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int matrixY = -matrix.Height/2; matrixY < matrix.Height/2; matrixY++)
      for (int matrixX = -matrix.Width/2; matrixX < matrix.Width/2; matrixX++) {
        // these coordinates will be outside the bitmap near all edges
        int sourceX = x + matrixX;
        int sourceY = y + matrixY;
        
        if (sourceX < 0)
          sourceX = 0;

        if (sourceX >= bitmap.Width)
          sourceX = bitmap.Width - 1;
        
        if (sourceY < 0)
          sourceY = 0;

        if (sourceY >= bitmap.Height)
          sourceY = bitmap.Height - 1;
        
        sum += source[sourceX, sourceY];
      }
    }

    // factor and clamp sum
    
    destination[x, y] = sum;
  }
}
```

You might need an extra loop to handle each color channel which need to be processed separately. I couldn't immediately see where in your code you might be doing that from all the cryptic variables.

Comment: As you said I need one more loop for the color, that's why you see 5 loops there ;) I didn't realize the mistake, thanks for clearing that out. As to solution, can't I just add a few if statements to make this work?? I don't really have any other idea in my head right now.

Comment: Which loop does the color exactly? The extra one that goes to `m.Height`? Shouldn't it rather go to 3 for red, green and blue? And yes, `if` statements would be OK for clamping. `if (x < 0) x = 0;` etc. There's probably a more performant way that avoid conditionals inside the loop, but you should try to get it working correctly before worrying about that.

Comment: This is the line that calculates the value of the color: `nPixel += (pSrc[(m.Width * (i + 1)) - 1 - r + stride * j] * m.Arr[j, i]);`

Comment: And this is the line for setting it: `p[(m.Width * (m.Height / 2 + 1)) - 1 - r + stride * (m.Height / 2)] = (byte)nPixel;`. The problem is that this pSrc[] goes out of memory bound when I hit the edge and I'm not sure how to put it into if statement

Comment: And `r` is set up to loop to the height of the matrix which is weird. Shouldn't it just be 3 or 4? The rest of the math is odd too...

Comment: r is 3 for 3x3 matrix, 5 for 5x5 matrix and so on

Comment: @AleksanderLipka: So which variable is for the color channels? For the third time the number of color channels is not the limit for any of your five loops.

Comment: You can see from where I got the idea for my function here: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2008/Image-Processing-for-Dummies-with-C-and-GDI-Part) The author also doesn't take into the account the edges

Comment: I don't think you should trust that tutorial. It seems to be doing a lot of things wrong. For one it's ignoring the edges, and in addition to that it's aligning the top left corner of the matrix with the output pixel rather than the center cell of the matrix.

Comment: Ok, so I tried to add this if to the last for loop: `if (y >= nHeight - (m.Size/2)) {//empty  } else { nPixel += (pSrc[(m.Size * (i + 1)) - 1 - r + stride * j] * m.Arr[j, i]); }` but it just gives me a black line, what is the formula for calculating edges?

Comment: @AleksanderLipka: I've put in the whole clamping logic. I can't make it any more clear than this without writing your entire code for you. If you can't get your pointer math sorted out, I suggest writing a slow version with plain `GetPixel` and simple coordinates first, and then refactoring it if needed. And an if with `// empty` in it is pointless