# Sharpen Filter in the spatial domain

Tags: c#, image-processing, filter, bitmap, convolution

The following routine is to sharpen an 8 bit indexed grayscale only.

```
   public static Bitmap Sharpen(Bitmap image, double strength)
    {
        using (var bitmap1 = image as Bitmap)
        {
            if (bitmap1 != null)
            {
                var bitmap = bitmap1.Clone() as Bitmap;

                int width = image.Width;
                int height = image.Height;

                // Create sharpening filter.
                const int filterSize = 5;

                var filter = new double[,]
                {
                    {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
                    {-1,  2,  2,  2, -1},
                    {-1,  2, 16,  2, -1},
                    {-1,  2,  2,  2, -1},
                    {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1}
                };

                int channels = sizeof(byte);
                double bias = 1.0 - strength;
                double factor = strength / 16.0;
                const int halfOfFilerSize = filterSize / 2;

                byte[,] result = new byte[image.Width, image.Height];

                // Lock image bits for read/write.
                if (bitmap != null)
                {
                    BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
                                                                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                                                PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

                    // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
                    int memorySize = bitmapData.Stride * height;
                    byte[] memory = new byte[memorySize];

                    // Copy the RGB values into the local array.
                    Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, memory, 0, memorySize);

                    int rgb;
                    // Fill the color array with the new sharpened color values.

                    for (int y = halfOfFilerSize; y < height - halfOfFilerSize; y++)
                    {
                        for (int x = halfOfFilerSize; x < width - halfOfFilerSize; x++)
                        {
                            for (int filterY = 0; filterY < filterSize; filterY++)
                            {
                                double grayShade = 0.0;

                                for (int filterX = 0; filterX < filterSize; filterX++)
                                {
                                    int imageX = (x - halfOfFilerSize + filterX + width) % width;
                                    int imageY = (y - halfOfFilerSize + filterY + height) % height;

                                    rgb = imageX * bitmapData.Stride + channels * imageY;

                                    grayShade += memory[rgb + 0] * filter[filterX, filterY];
                                }

                                rgb = x * bitmapData.Stride + channels * y;

                                int b = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * grayShade + (bias * memory[rgb + 0])), 0), 255);

                                result[x, y] = (byte)b;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Update the image with the sharpened pixels.
                    for (int x = halfOfFilerSize; x < width - halfOfFilerSize; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = halfOfFilerSize; y < height - halfOfFilerSize; y++)
                        {
                            rgb = y * bitmapData.Stride + 3 * x;

                            memory[rgb + 0] = result[x, y];
                        }
                    }

                    // Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap.
                    Marshal.Copy(memory, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, memorySize);

                    // Release image bits.
                    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
                }

                return bitmap;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**This routine throws an exception in the following line:**

```
grayShade += memory[rgb + 0] * filter[filterX, filterY];
```

[image]

**What am I calculating wrong?**

.

.

**P.S.** GUI code:

```
    private void sharpenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap sharpened = ImageSharpener.Sharpen(_inputImage, 0.5);

        sharpenedPictureBox.Image = sharpened;
    }
```

Comment: Divide to conquer, use a debugger and step through your code to find the cause ! :) BTW isn't your filter supposed to go through `-halfSize` to `+halfSize` for each pixel and handle borders by either clamping or wrapping ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

`rgb = imageX * bitmapData.Stride + channels * imageY;`

should be:

`rgb = imageY * bitmapData.Stride + channels * imageX;`

And this:

`rgb = x * bitmapData.Stride + channels * y;`

should be:

`rgb = y * bitmapData.Stride + channels * x;`

Also, you should not multiply by `channels`, that's already part of `bitmapData.Stride`. Also, note that `channels = sizeof(byte)`, that's just 1, not 3 (as implied by `rgb = y * bitmapData.Stride + 3 * x;` ).

After fixing the errors above, your filter may still not work. Either debug, or compare to solution here: [C# Convolution filter for any size matrix (1x1, 3x3, 5x5, ...) not fully applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35855950/c-sharp-convolution-filter-for-any-size-matrix-1x1-3x3-5x5-not-fully-ap)

Comment: @anonymous See link added to bottom of answer.

Comment: Can u please answer this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302863/filter-spatial-domain-versus-frequency-domain