# Xamarin: Converting .NET Convolution function to C# Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a working convolution function from my WinForms project, which I posted a while ago: 
[C# Convolution filter for any size matrix (1x1, 3x3, 5x5, ...) not fully applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35855950/c-sharp-convolution-filter-for-any-size-matrix-1x1-3x3-5x5-not-fully-ap)

Now I need to tranform this function without using System.Drawing.Imaging which is not available in Xamarin.
 For that I need to use other libraries like Android.Graphics which do not have BitmapData structures.

 I am close to the end with my conversion but I messed something up - my application terminates while computing the function.

 Here is the code after my conversion:

```
using System;
using Dicom.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Android.Graphics;
using Java.Nio;

public static Bitmap ConvolutionFunction(Bitmap bitmap, ConvMatrix m)
    {
        if (0 == m.Factor)
            return bitmap;

        int size = bitmap.Width * bitmap.Height * 4;

        var mutableBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, bitmap.GetConfig());

        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.Allocate(size);
        ByteBuffer bufSrc = ByteBuffer.Allocate(size);

        bitmap.CopyPixelsToBuffer(buf);
        byte[] byt = new byte[buf.Remaining()];
        buf.Get(byt);

        bitmap.CopyPixelsToBuffer(bufSrc);
        byte[] bytSrc = new byte[bufSrc.Remaining()];
        buf.Get(bytSrc);

        int stride = bitmap.Width;

        System.IntPtr Scan0 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(byt.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(byt, 0, Scan0, byt.Length);

        System.IntPtr SrcScan0 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytSrc.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(bytSrc, 0, Scan0, byt.Length);

        unsafe
        {
            byte* p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;
            byte* pSrc = (byte*)(void*)SrcScan0;
            int nOffset = stride - bitmap.Width * m.Size;
            int nWidth = bitmap.Width - (m.Size - 1);
            int nHeight = bitmap.Height - (m.Size - 1);

            int nPixel = 0;

            for (int y = 0; y < nHeight; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < nWidth; x++)
                {
                    for (int r = 0; r < m.Size; r++)
                    {
                        nPixel = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < m.Size; i++)
                            for (int j = 0; j < m.Size; j++)
                            {
                                nPixel += (pSrc[(m.Size * (i + 1)) - 1 - r + stride * j] * m.Arr[j, i]);
                            }

                        nPixel /= m.Factor;
                        nPixel += m.Offset;

                        if (nPixel < 0) nPixel = 0;
                        if (nPixel > 255) nPixel = 255;
                        p[(m.Size * (m.Size / 2 + 1)) - 1 - r + stride * (m.Size / 2)] = (byte)nPixel;
                    }
                    p += m.Size;
                    pSrc += m.Size;
                }

                p += nOffset;
                pSrc += nOffset;
            }
        }

        ByteBuffer retBuf = ByteBuffer.Wrap(byt);
        mutableBitmap.CopyPixelsFromBuffer(retBuf);

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Scan0);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(SrcScan0);

        return mutableBitmap;
    }
}
```

I haven't change anything inside unsafe { .. } section. I may have messed something up with IntPtr and stride. 
Please help

Comment: Try to add try-catch block, it should help you to understand why your app terminates.

Comment: If you do not get any exceptions. You can look up Xamarin logs by this way, `Visual Studio> Help>Xamarin>Open logs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I found a very fast convolution function that was implemented in Xamarin android, here is the result:

```
    public static Bitmap GaussianFilter(Bitmap image)
    {
        float[] conv_matrix =
        { 1.0f/8.0f, 1.0f/4.0f, 1.0f/8.0f,
          1.0f/4.0f, 1.0f/2.0f, 1.0f/4.0f,
          1.0f/8.0f, 1.0f/4.0f, 1.0f/8.0f };

        return createBitmap_convolve(image, conv_matrix);
    }

    public static Bitmap createBitmap_convolve(Bitmap src, float[] coefficients)
    {
        //Fast method using android solution: ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3()
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(src.Width,
          src.Height, src.GetConfig());

        RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.Create(Android.App.Application.Context);

        Allocation input = Allocation.CreateFromBitmap(renderScript, src);
        Allocation output = Allocation.CreateFromBitmap(renderScript, result);

        ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3 convolution = ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3
          .Create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
        convolution.SetInput(input);
        convolution.SetCoefficients(coefficients);
        convolution.ForEach(output);

        output.CopyTo(result);
        renderScript.Destroy();

        return result;
    }
```

And here is the solution for Xamarin iOS if someone needs it:

```
    using CoreImage;
    using UIKit;
    using CoreGraphics;

    public static UIImage GaussianFilter(UIImage image)
    {
        CIImage ciImage = new CIImage(image);
        //ciImage.CreateByApplyingGaussianBlur(2);

        var gaussianFilter = new CIGaussianBlur() { Image = ciImage, Radius = 0.8f};
        CIImage output = gaussianFilter.OutputImage;
        var context = CIContext.FromOptions(null);
        var cgimage = context.CreateCGImage(output, output.Extent);
        var uiImage = UIImage.FromImage(cgimage);

        return uiImage;
    }
```